# Polymer 1.0: Two-way bindings with input elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element

## Code

Consider the following Polymer custom element:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">

<template>
    <input type="text" value="{{value}}">
    <button>Reset</button>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'test-element',
    properties: {
        'value': {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            notify: true,
            value: null
        }
    }
});
</script>

</dom-module>
```

I use this custom element in my index.html as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="test-element.html">
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <test-element value="test"></test-element>
</body>
</html>
```

## Question

I believe I have declared the `value` property as a two-way binding (`notify: true`); yet when I click on the input and type in some text (say, `"foo"`), it is not reflected in the model (i.e. a call to `document.querySelector('test-element').value` returns the value I set in index.html, `"test"`).  Interestingly enough, the `value` attribute of the input changes correctly, but the value property of my test-element does not.  What am I missing?

I should also note that a call to `document.querySelector('test-element').setAttribute('value', 'bar')` works properly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First note that the `notify` and `reflectToAttribute` fields on the `value` property tell it how to react to it's parent not about how to bind to a child.

IOW, `notify: true` means to make `value` two-way bindable from the *outside*, not from the inside. `reflectToAttribute: true` tells Polymer to write `value` to an attribute every time it changes (not good for performance).

When you do a binding like `<x-element foo="{{value}}">`, it's *x-element* that decides if `foo` is two-way bindable.

Native elements like `input` do not have two-way binding support built in, instead use Polymer's event-observer syntax to two-way bind to an input. Like so
`<input value="{{value::change}}">`.

This tells Polymer to update `this.value` from `input.value` whenever the `input` fires a `change` event.

Comment: Thanks.  The inside/outside distinction now makes sense to me.  I've requested an edit adding a link to the documentation.

Comment: I'd just like to point out a nuance [Scott Miles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2192324/scott-miles) in that the `readOnly` field in the property declaration doesn't solely govern the property's behavior with regard to elements outside the local DOM, but also elements inside the local DOM as well.  IOW, if I set a property as read-only it's read-only for for children as well as ancestors.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not to say that read-only properties are never modifiable; a read-only property _is modifiable_ via a special setter method, but as far as I can see it's not through use of the data binding API.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal

Answer (score 16):

You need to change this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{value}}">
```

into

```
<input type="text" value="{{value::input}}">
```

try [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ABShlYbsborDIxTAe9i?p=preview). This says for polymer to listen to input's events. Explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#two-way-native) (not very clearly IMO).

Comment: You're right, is kind of buried in the docs somewhere; I've edited the answer above with a link to the docs (waiting to be peer reviewed), but I'll also paste it here for anyone to find it easily:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#two-way-native

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andrey and Scott Miles, both of these solutions will work to get 2-way-bind with a native HTML input box.

`<input type="text" value="{{value::input}}">`

`<input type="text" value="{{value::change}}">`

With an important difference:

::change will only fire when the text box loses focus or enter is pressed.

::input will fire on every keypress.